# Is every bounded derivation from compact to finite rank operators inner?

Tags: operator-algebras, compact-operators

This question is related to [Derivation into dense ideal of Banach algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381737/derivation-into-dense-ideal-of-banach-algebras).  Depending on which way it goes, an answer to one might answer the other (this is elaborated below).

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $K(H)$ the algebra of compact operators on $H$, and $F(H)$ the ideal in $K(H)$ of finite rank operators.  Suppose that $D:K(H)\to F(H)$ is a bounded derivation, meaning $D$ is a bounded linear map such that $D(ab)=aD(b)+D(a)b$ for all $a,b\in K(H)$.

**Question:**
Must $D$ be an inner derivation, in the sense that there exists $x\in F(H)$ such that $D(a)=ax-xa$ for all $a\in K(H)$?

---

Some context including a reformulation of the question:

1. In the question linked above, there is a dense ideal $I$ in a Banach algebra $A$, the hypothesis is that every bounded derivation $A\to I$ is inner, and the question is whether this implies every bounded derivation $A\to A$ is inner.  If the answer to that question is yes, then the answer to this one is no, because $F(H)$ is a dense ideal in $K(H)$ and $K(H)$ has outer derivations, e.g. $a\mapsto aS-Sa$ where $S$ is a shift operator. Hence, if the answer to this one is yes, the answer to that one is no.  But a no answer on either wouldn't necessarily help answer the other.
2. Every bounded derivation $K(H)\to K(H)$ has the form $a\mapsto ax-xa$ for some $x\in B(H)$ (proof appears in [Hanno's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2199194/) at the linked question), and every $x\in B(H)$ defines such a derivation on $K(H)$.  These can be outer as indicated above.  But here the much stricter requirement is that the range is in $F(H)$, and the question can be reformulated as:

**Question, Version 2**: If $x$ is in $B(H)$ and $ax-xa$ has finite rank for all $a\in K(H)$, must $x$ be scalar plus finite rank?